# How do i make prediction intervals without normally distributed residuals?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval

I have made predictions for the amount of conversions of a particular website. After predicting the amount for every day. I looked for ways to get a prediction interval for every day. The residuals are plotted as follows: [Residuals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpwh8.png)

From my knowledge this is not normally distributed. I am curious if there is a way to get prediction intervals.